# GCloud Compute Engine won't delete or stop. Keeps respawing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-compute-engine

I have a google compute VM instance that will not stop or be killed.

I don't know where it came from and I can't delete it or pause it. I don't have anything running on it nor is has anything scheduled with it.

'gke-cluster-1-default-pool-....`
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a VM from Google Container Engine. In the left menu, navigate to Container Engine and check if you have any clusters created. If a cluster was created and then removed it is possible that the VM did not get cleaned up properly.

In you dashboard, there should be an Activity tab. You can use this to filter the activity on the account to see if someone created a Google Container Engine cluster.

Comment: You are correct. I deleted the container and was able to delete the cluster. Thanks. I'll mark your answer as accepted when it allows me